# BottomSheetDialog is applying under the bar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm creating an actionSheet but it's getting under the bar, I've tried some codes, looked at other questions, but nothing worked, initially I saw that it was a bug, but I didn't find any possible fixes

does anyone know how i could fix it?

[action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY0jF.png)

myclass

```
private void openDialog(View v) {
    //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View sheet = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sheet_foto, null);
    BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(activity);

    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheet);
    TextView camera_sel = sheet.findViewById(R.id.camera);
    TextView gallery_sel = sheet.findViewById(R.id.gallery);

    camera_sel.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
        //takePhotoFromCamera();
        bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
    });

    gallery_sel.setOnClickListener(v12 -> {
        //takePhotoFromGallery();
        bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
    });
    bottomSheetDialog.show();
}
```

Layout actionSheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="-56dp"
android:padding="4dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/camera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_take_photo"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="Camera"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_add_photo"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="Gallery"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

here is the click that calls openDialog

```
public void onClickPesquisar() {
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(identificacaoTrabalhador.getText().toString())){
        openDialog();
    }else{
        
    }
}
private void openDialog() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View sheet = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sheet_foto, null);
    BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);

    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheet);
    TextView camera_sel = sheet.findViewById(R.id.camera);
    TextView gallery_sel = sheet.findViewById(R.id.gallery);

    camera_sel.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
        //takePhotoFromCamera();
        bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
    });

    gallery_sel.setOnClickListener(v12 -> {
        //takePhotoFromGallery();
        bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
    });
    bottomSheetDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: can you show me openDialog() method call in your activity?

Comment: edited the question, put the flame code, I simply call it the Main activity